# Shell script error: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: shell

I am getting a syntax error with the following shell script and I just can't figure out why:

```
./query_certs.sh: 22: ./query_certs.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Is it because of nested if-else statements?

Thanks in advance.

```
# Check how many arguments we received
if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [MODE] DESTINATION_IP" >&2
    echo "MODE may be one of the following" >&2
    echo "none - shell script will ask interactively" >&2
    echo "HTTP - query the certificate from HTTPS (port 443)" >&2
    echo "LDAP - query the certificate from an AD  (port 636" >&2
    echo "FTP - query the certificate from an FTPs (ports 990/989)" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$#" == 2 ]; then
    MODE=$1
    if [ "$MODE" == "HTTP" ]; then
        QUERY="foo"
    elif [ "$MODE" == "LDAP" ]; then
        QUERY="bar"
    elif [ "$MODE" == "FTP" ]; then
        QUERY="baz"
    else
        echo "Please choose a mode  (HTTP | LDAP | FTP):" # <<< that's line 22
        options=("HTTP" "LDAP" "FTP";)
        select opt  in "${options[@]}" do
            case $opt in
                "HTTP")
                    echo "Selected HTTP"
                    ;;
                "LDAP")
                    echo "Selected LDAP"
                    ;;
                "FTP")
                    echo "Selected FTP"
                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
fi
```

Comment: @user1192748 : Since you get a line number, the least you can do is to indicate, which is line 22 in your code.

Comment: There is an extra `;` in `options=("HTTP" "LDAP" "FTP";)` and next line has a missing `;` before `do`

Comment: @user1934428 I added a reference to line 22 in the code.

Comment: @anubhava: thanks, I fixed it. Somehow, still getting an error for the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it myself. One important thing I didn't mention in my original post (added it now so it might be helpful for others): initially I had the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

As I wanted to have POSIX conform. Seems like some routines I am using aren't POSIX conform. Hence, I changed to using bash. Furthermore, there were more mistakes, which are fixed as follows:

```
# Check how many arguments we received
if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [MODE] DESTINATION_IP" >&2
    echo "MODE may be one of the following" >&2
    echo "none - shell script will ask interactively" >&2
    echo "HTTP - query the certificate from HTTPS (port 443)" >&2
    echo "LDAP - query the certificate from an AD  (port 636" >&2
    echo "FTP - query the certificate from an FTPs (ports 990/989)" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$#" = 2 ]; then
    MODE=$1
    if [ "$MODE" = "HTTP" ]; then
        QUERY="foo"
    elif [ "$MODE" = "LDAP" ]; then
        QUERY="bar"
    elif [ "$MODE" = "FTP" ]; then
        QUERY="baz"
    else
        PS3='Please choose a mode  (HTTP | LDAP | FTP):'
        options=("HTTP" "LDAP" "FTP")
        select opt  in "${options[@]}" do
            case $opt in
                "HTTP")
                    echo "Selected HTTP"
                    ;;
                "LDAP")
                    echo "Selected LDAP"
                    ;;
                "FTP")
                    echo "Selected FTP"
                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You **did** mention implicitly that you are looking for a Posix solution, because you supplied the `shell` tag, and I suspected that the offending line is the assignment to  `options`, which is not valid in Posix shell, but  you said that line 22 were the line before, i.e. the `echo`, and this line is perfectly fine under Posix and bash.